# How to force commit to database before end of transaction block in kotlin exposed?

Tags: kotlin-exposed

I am using the JetBrains Exposed library available [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) on Github.

The [documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki) mentions that all database queries should be performed in a `transaction{ }` block. The changes to database are then commited at the end of the transaction.

Is it possible to force commit changes ***before*** the end of transaction block? See pseudo code below.

```kotlin
Transaction {
    /*someDatabaseOperation()*/
    forceCommit()
    /*moreDatabaseOperations()*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the `connection.autoCommit` feature within a transaction block.

```kotlin
transaction {
    connection.autoCommit /*below operations will be comitted sequentially*/
    someDatabaseOperation()
    moreDatabaseOperations()
}
```

see related discussion [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/306).

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
transaction {
    /*someDatabaseOperation()*/

    commit()

    /*moreDatabaseOperations()*/

    rollback() // cancel changes. Back to last commit.
}
```